# JPA Eclipse fails to update foreign key on merge() call

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jpa, jpql

i've found this problem in a lot of posts but i can't find a solution.
I have one entity:

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name="UTENTI")
 @NamedQueries({
 @NamedQuery(name="Utenti.findAll", query="SELECT u FROM Utenti u"),
 @NamedQuery(name="Utenti.findByEmail", query="SELECT u FROM Utenti u WHERE u.userId = :mail")
  })
 public class Utenti implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @Column(name="ID_UTENTE", nullable = false)   
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private BigDecimal id;

  @Column(name="USER_ID",unique=true)
  private String userId;

  private String cognome;

  @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
  private Date dataDiNascita;

  private String nome;

  private String password;

  private String ruolo;



 @OneToMany(mappedBy="user",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
 private List<Form> forms;

 @ManyToMany(mappedBy="users",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)  
 private List<Groups> groups;


  @OneToMany(mappedBy="utente",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
     private List<CodicePromozionale> codes;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="owner",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
     private List<PacchettoAcquistato> acquisti;


      /*getters and setters*/
```

and another entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="GROUPS")

public class Groups implements Serializable {


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="GROUPID", nullable=false)
private String groupId;

@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="USER_GROUP",joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="GROUPID",referencedColumnName="GROUPID")},inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="USERID",referencedColumnName="USER_ID")})
private List<Utenti> users;
```

if i change userId inside my stateless bean and then call merge like so:

```
 this.user.setUserId(newUserId);
 this.em.merge(user);
```

where this.em is the EntityManager

i get this error:

```
 Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-     3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
 Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:   Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`traveldreamdb`.`user_group`, CONSTRAINT `FK_USER_GROUP_USERID` FOREIGN KEY (`USERID`) REFERENCES `UTENTI` (`USER_ID`))
 Error Code: 1451
 Call: UPDATE UTENTI SET USER_ID = ? WHERE (ID_UTENTE = ?)
bind => [2 parameters bound]
```

why this happens if i have specified the cascadeType.ALL?How can i resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

From the exception message, it says you have another table in your database, name is `user_group`. It has a column `user_id`. This column is referencing to the `user_id` column of `UTENTI` table. So, whenever you are trying to update this value, the other table `user_group` faces the problem as the reference is updated.

Comment: user_group is the table created by the join over userId and groupId as you can see in the entity groups where it is annotated. What have i to do?why is it not automatically updated?

Comment: I don't think JPA handle the reference while updating. So, first you have to delete(or changing the user_id into any other values) the rows from user_group which are referencing with the user_id. Only then you can perform UPDATE operation.

Comment: how can i change the user_id i user_group? i have no entity for user_group because it is generated as a join table. what's the meaning of CascadeType if it doesn't update nothing? @Sabuj Hassan

Comment: You have to create an entity for User_Group also, because you have `traveldreamdb`.`user_group` this.

Comment: how is it possible that there isn't another way?i can't  managed all this kind of relation like so.